# Symfony 5 exception Could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, symfony5

I am making my first app with Symfony and when i setup my database (doesn't matter if it's postgresql or mysql).

I have an error "could not find driver" three time.
One in PDOConnection.php line 38.

Other in Exception.php line 18.

And last one in AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 128.

What i made : i check the php path i also check all the extensions. I check if i fill correctly .env and i check those folders.

PHP version : 7.4

And mysql in docker containers: mysql:5.7.

I really have no idea what to do now

***UPDATE:***

The problem (for me) was the command `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

if you have the same problem try `symfony doctrine:database:create`

Comment: Did you [installed PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) PHP extension?

Comment: @greeflas in cmd i made php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());" i have line 21 [21]=> PDO. is it the right one ? Or an other one ?

Comment: i also checked in C:\php\ext and i have php_pdo_mysql.dll so i guess yeah i have it

Comment: You need the PDO, pdo_mysql and mysqli extensions.  Double check your get_loaded_extensions output.  I suspect you are missing the mysqli extension.

Comment: i have the extension php_mysqli.dll in C:\php\ext but you probably got right here is the result of the print: https://gyazo.com/99c417efa735bd515ccc0575ba84e2d1

Answer (score 1):

do you use .env file? I have same problem and after a day of disable/enable pdo without any effect, i found that symfony auto add a line to my .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8
```

That make my database url wrong and error not found pdo fire because of postgresql not mysql

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you use Docker, but in your question you mentioned Windows cmd. I suppose, you check PDO extension in your host system, not in container. You need to log into your Docker PHP container and check it there. In Windows Desktop version of Docker there is a button near each container to open command-line interface. You also can use command:

```
docker exec -it <here goes your container name>
```

To find out what your container name is, you can use command

```
docker ps
```

UPDATE:

To start your project not in Docker, bun on Windows-host itself, you can use very helpful mini-server, provided by Symfony. Run this command inside your project directory:

```
symfony serve
```

It will start local server, available by default at address https://127.0.0.1:8000/.

However, keep in mind, that if your project requires database, you will need to have [MySQL Server for Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) installed on your host system too.

Comment: i used docker because they said in one article i need it for my db for the configuration but i don't know how docker really work, how can i do this without docker then ? i have a container for mysql and the basic one "getting started"

Comment: @JeanBane Updated my answer. However, I personally advise you to get along with Docker. This way is more propper, easy and documented.

Comment: i launch my server by using symfony server:start so i guess symfony serve is an alias. but i'll try your update. (im lost with docker so i followed instruction provided by the blog Auth0). Thanks for the solution i'll give you feedback if this solution doesn't work too

Comment: it's really weird i did this. symfony console doctrine:database:create and no errors i have the followed message  "created database 'symfony' for connection named default". looks good right?

Comment: @JeanBane I guess so! :D